# Dynamic database name to be used in the same query without using stored proc

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to do something like this in MySql:

select *, CONCAT(schema_name,'.','my_table') as **database_name** from table_a a
inner join table_b b on b.id = a.id
inner join **database_name** c on a.id2 = c.id;

Basically, database_name's value is taken from the existing query and also it will be used in the same query.

Is it possible to do something like this without using stored proc?
If not, is it possible to do this in Java without using loops?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this in a single query. It doesn't require a stored proc, though.

The **identifiers** in a query cannot be variable; MySQL needs to actually *know* the names of the objects (tables, columns, functions, et al.) when the SQL text is submitted; the identifiers can't vary at execution time.

This doesn't require a stored proc, but it does require two separate SELECT statements. One SELECT to retrieve the database identifiers. And the values from that can be used to formulate a string that contains SQL text for another SELECT to be submitted to the database.

Comment: what I am doing right now as a workaround(or probably the only solution I can think of) is that in java, I am looping all the results and then inside the loop, there is another select statement. I think that this would cause performance issues in the long run specially when there is a lot of records included and also, this query will be used in a search screen of the admin user so there will be a lot of records expected.

Comment: @user15167776: If you have dozens or hundreds of tables to query, you're either going to need to run dozens or hundreds of queries, or combine the queries of the individual tables into some huge-a$$ `UNION ALL` queries. But, such is the way it is when you have a boatload of tables to query.